# Unexpected result from #cmakedefine substitution

Tags: cmake, c-preprocessor, config

Suppose that in my `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
check_function_exists(getopt HAVE_GETOPT)
configure_file(config.h.in config.h @ONLY)
```

and in `config.h.in` I have:

```
#cmakedefine HAVE_GETOPT @HAVE_GETOPT@
#cmakedefine STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT @HAVE_GETOPT@
```

I expect to see

```
#define HAVE_GETOPT 1
#define STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT 1
```

after the pass. instead, I get:

```
#define HAVE_GETOPT 1 
/* #undef STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT */
```

why the difference in behavior?

Notes:

- Using cMake v3.5.1 and GNU/Linux Mint 18.3 with a kernel 4.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the desired behavior, don't use `cmakedefine`, but use `cmakedefine01` instead (note the trailing `01`). In your example:

```
#cmakedefine01 HAVE_GETOPT @HAVE_GETOPT@
#cmakedefine01 STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT @HAVE_GETOPT@
```

Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html

Comment: `#cmakedefine01` doesn't give the desired results: like `#cmakedefine` it checks the value of the **CMake variable** (`STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT` in the second case). Moreover, everything which follows the variable in the template file will prepend the 0/1: `#cmakedefine01 STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT @HAVE_GETOPT@` will produce (literally!) `#define STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT 1 0`. Such prepending is noted in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For `#cmakedefine` you cannot use different variables in the second argument then in the first one. You have to define `STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT` before running `configure_file`.

```
check_function_exists(getopt HAVE_GETOPT)
set(STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT HAVE_GETOPT)
configure_file(config.h.in config.h @ONLY)
```

Comment: Re-reading your question and your comment to the other question, this might be the right answer. As you accepted my first one, I post this as a second answer

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/configure_file.html) for `configure_file` is clear:

---

... input lines of the form:

```
#cmakedefine VAR ...
```

will be replaced with either:

```
#define VAR ...
```

or:

```
/* #undef VAR */
```

depending on whether VAR is set in CMake ...

---

Only value of *VAR* has a sence, everything after it is unrelated to CMake choice between `#define` and `#undef`.

Because of that, `#cmakedefine HAVE_GETOPT` is transformed to `#define`, but `#cmakedefine STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT` is transformed to `#undef` (since variable *STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT* is not set in CMake code).

Comment: On the contrary, the documentation you linked to is unclear. It suggests that `#define FOO_STRING @FOO_STRING@` will perform a substitution, unlike what you've quoted...

Comment: Hm, the quotation tells only about `#cmakedefine`, not about `#define`. And your code uses `#cmakedefine`. I see no problem in docs.

Answer (score 0):

to get the desired behaviour...

```
#define HAVE_GETOPT 1
#define STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT 1
```

try

```
#cmakedefine HAVE_GETOPT @HAVE_GETOPT@
#ifdef HAVE_GETOPT
#define STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT ${HAVE_GETOPT}
#endif
```

...using the cmake reference ${...} in this way has worked for me, the #cmakedefine line will be processed as usual by cmake and the following 3 lines will be output to the config.h file with the proper value in place of ${...}

the end result is that if HAVE_GETOPT is set in the CMakeLists.txt file then STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT will also be defined with the same value, conversely, if HAVE_GETOPT is not defined then STDLIB_HAS_GETOPT will also not be defined.

I haven't seen any documentation (yet) that confirms this behaviour but it does work.